# maintaining different package.json and config giles for dev and prod

Tags: node.js, git

I have a production branch and a development branch on git.

When merging changes from development branch to production, I would like to ensure that my package.json and gulpfile.js do not get merged in the changes.

How can I prevent this from happening? For deployment sake, I want to preserve productions package.json and gullpfile.js as being untouched with any possible changes to developments package and gulpfile

Answer (score 0):

You can use Git attributes to tell Git to use different merge strategies for specific files in your project. One very useful option is to tell Git to not try to merge specific files when they have conflicts, but rather to use your side of the merge over someone else’s.

Full article : http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Merge-Strategies

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best practice would be to save all files in both branches, then define in the deployment process which file should be copied to root (this file will be the one used).
In my opinion it is confusing to maintain many files per branch (especially when working with git flow).

If you want it even "cleaner", in my opinion (and I think it cover most scenarios, but it might not fit your needs), you should have only one gulpfile.js, as well as package.json and an additional config file that manages the differences (this file can be copied on deployment, or you can choose which config to use by env variable).